# Pulse Transformer design problem: cant understand for sure whats the reason or irregular output waveform?

Tags: mosfet, inductor, pulse

A ferrite core pulse transformer provided with 12V PWM signal (as primary winding input voltage) as shown in Fig-1, produces irregular output voltage across the secondary winding as shown in Fig-2. I dont know why the ferrite core pulse transformer is doing like this; is it due to saturation of ferrite core pulse transformer or maybe low inductance of transformer primary winding? Pulse transformer winding ratio is 1:1
[image]

Comment: The longer your pulse the more like DC it becomes. Transformers don't output DC.

Comment: I have added a capacitor in series with the transformer primary winding to black DC voltage

Comment: Core saturation. Apply Vt=NAB. What B do you med up with?

Comment: well, i am taking B approx 1000, by the way, in Vt=NABm what is "t" ?

Comment: A transformer is effectively a high-pass filter.

Comment: No you are not. t is time in seconds. Everything in SI.

Comment: What is producing the PWM waveform, and how much current can it supply? Please show the actual waveform with timing.

Comment: A microcontroller is producing the PWM waveform, and to enhance the current i am using a complementary pair of transistors to enhance the primary winding current.

Comment: If you have a manufactured pulse transformer, you also have a parameter: voltage product V*s, this means 12V multiplied by max. pulse width time. It's what @winny wants to tell you. The problem is the core saturation.

Comment: thank you for your comment, will look into the saturation issue